# How to Convert string array into simple array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I know that, this question was asked too many times, but it was an different case.

I have already tried too many ways, but doesn't found any workaround.

```
$array = ["9","8","7","6","5"]; //javascript JSON.stringify() output

json_decode($array); //expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
explode(',', $array); // Array ( [0] => ["7" [1] => "6"] )
```

I had also tried with `array_shift()`,`array_walk()`, `map()` but still no luck.

**output**

```
array(
   [0] => 9
   [1] => 8
   [2] => 7
   [3] => 6
   [4] => 5
)
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: @Pointy. simply want to create my output array from given array.

Comment: What is an "indexed array"? And **none** of that looks like JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy as i shown in the output.

Comment: just print_r($array);

Comment: And certainly not jQuery.

Comment: json_deocde gives me correct output but i cannot further proceed on it.

Comment: @RuchishParikh i want to store that array.

Comment: Check this demo : https://eval.in/555878

Comment: Check deom with use of array : https://eval.in/555881

Comment: @RuchishParikh not working for me still prints` ["9","8"] `

Comment: paste your code what you have tried.

Comment: @RuchishParikh `implode("," ,$array);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109496/discussion-between-ruchish-parikh-and-insane-skull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear, but if you firstly get your JSON as string, maybe you'll get what you want?

```
<?php

$array = <<<END
["9","8","7","6","5"]
END;

$php_array = json_decode($array);

$string = join(',', $php_array);
$output = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: well , i got the text as `9,8,7..`

Comment: finally - yes... I used a telepathy to decide that this is exactly what you need. I'm sorry if I was mistaken

Comment: you were correct, still need one more process, `explode()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `implode()`.

```
$array = ["9","8","7","6","5"];
print_r($array);
$string = implode(",",$array);
echo "string :".$string;
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 5
)

String: 9,8,7,6,5
```

**Live Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/555881)**

Comment: it will not work, i had already tried 100 times.

Comment: I am sharing you live demo.

Comment: Thanks, for your efforts buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
json_decode($array,true);
```

May this help you